# Proof that, for $u \in H^1$, $\{ u > \alpha \}$ is a quasi open set

Tags: elliptic-pde, geometric-measure-theory

I am reading the monograph by A. Henrot, *Extremum problems for eigenvalues of elliptic operators*. In chapter 2, the notion of a quasi-open set is defined (see the relevant definitions at the end of this post, copied from a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3318160/example-of-a-quasi-open-set-and-how-the-capacity-of-the-set-fits-in-it) on Math SE). It is then claimed that for $u \in H^1(D)$ ($D$ a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$) and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $\{ u > \alpha \}$ is a quasi-open set. I would like to understand why this is true (no proof is given).

I think the proof must somehow make use of the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, i.e., that $u(x) \in H^1(D)$ is Lebesgue almost everywhere equal to $\limsup_{r \to 0} |B_r(x)|^{-1} \int_{B_r(x)} u(y) dy$ (and this limsup is a limit Lebesgue almost everywhere). But I haven't been able to make any further progress, and I don't know why $\nabla u \in (L^1(D))^n$ is relevant. Any hints or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

First, in Definition 2.4.3, the capacity of compact $K \subseteq D$ is defined as

> Let $D$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For any compact subset $K$ in $D$,
> $$\text{cap}_D(K)= \inf \left\{\int_D|\nabla v|^2: v\in C_0^{\infty}, v\geq 1 \text{ surrounding } K \right\}.$$

The definition can be extended for an open subset $\omega$ of $D$ as

> $$\text{cap}_D(\omega):= \sup \{\text{cap}_D(K): K \text{ compact, } K\subseteq \omega\}$$

Quasi-open sets as in Definition 2.4.4 are defined as follows,

> A subset $\Omega$ of $D$ (a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$) is quasi-open if there exist a decreasing sequence of open sets $\omega_n$ such that
> $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to +\infty} \text{cap}_D(\omega_n)=0$$
> where $\Omega \cup \omega_n$ is open for all $n$ and $\text{cap}_D(\omega_n)$ is the capacity of $\omega_n$ relative to $D$.